# Could not compile dependency :idna after adding "timex" dependency.

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

After adding "timex" dependency I am facing this issue here is the error 
        ===> Command bare not found
        ** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :idna, "/usr/bin/rebar3 bare compile --paths "phoenix/_build/dev/lib/*/ebin"" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile idna", update it with "mix deps.update idna" or clean it with "mix deps.clean idna"

Comment: Which version of rebar3 is installed?  Which version of timex are you attempting to add? Sounds like a version mismatch somewhere.

Comment: Earlier it was rebar2.x. ...So I changed it to rebar3... Now I am get'g "Command bare not found" error.

Comment: Rebar2.x to Rebar3 isn't just a version change.  Rebar3 was totally rewritten.  There is no Rebar3 bare option.  Revert to Rebar2.x